# iOS VoIP Notifications not working on newly created app

Tags: ios, swift, voip

I have an old app that have VoIP implemented. Everything is working just fine. Now I'm creating a new one - new app in App Store(new bundle id), new certificates. I've never managed to receive a single voip notification in that app.

However if I put the old bundle id (from the old app that's working) as Bundle Identifier in the new app - it starts to receive the VoIP notifications. So the problem isn't in the new app code base.
I have created everything identical to the old one - certificates, capabilities, code.
Does anyone have experienced this?
Any solutions and suggestions are highly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server code which is sending voip. Check if the server is using new bundle id and certificates of the app. Ass you said, problem is not in your app code. It should be on server end.

Comment: That was my first thought, so I start testing with "houston" - it only needs the certificate and the voip token from the device. The result is the same.. The only difference I'm seeing is that the old app is approved and published in the store. The new one - isn't.

Comment: App approval is not an issue. Either your certificate is wrong or bundle id. Please ask  your server guy if he is using the code for production or development. Thats the issue that, I think it is. I once also stuck in such issue and the problem was there production code used during development.

Answer (score 0):

So yesterday I've submitted a ticket to apple. They said:

> Based on your reports that your Push Notifications have stopped working without any changes on your end, we suspect this could be due
> to continued use of the legacy Binary Interface which was retired
> March 31st, 2021 (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b).
>
> This change requires you to migrate your push servers to use the
> HTTP/2 API. Any push servers still using the legacy interface will be
> unable to connect to APNs, resulting in Push Notifications not
> working.
>
> More information about the HTTP/2 provider API can be found in these
> two WWDC sessions:
>
> - WWDC2015 Whats New in Notifications https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720/
> - WWDC2016 Whats New in the Apple Push Notification Service https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/724/

After migrating to HTTP/2 the pushes started working.